# LLDB: process launch failed: Lost debug server connection

Tags: ubuntu, llvm, lldb

I seem to have trouble getting lldb to run. I'm on a Ubuntu 14.04 system and downloaded lldb-4.0 via apt.

```
(lldb) target create dbgme
Current executable set to 'dbgme' (x86_64).
(lldb) process launch 
error: process launch failed: Lost debug server connection
```

I don't want to do any remote debugging. Just local debugging. Do I need to start the lldb-server either way? And if so how do I do that?

Comment: lldb uses lldbserver (debugserver on OS X) to debug even when local.  But you should not have to manage the server process by hand, lldb will take care of that behind the scenes.  You might try asking on the lldb-dev mailing list at lldb.llvm.org.  Most of the Linux lldb developers read and respond on that list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just installed lldb-3.9 via apt-get and it works out of the box. There seems to be something wrong with the 4.0 version.

Comment: If you have time to file a bug about this with the lldb.llvm.org bug reporter: https://llvm.org/bugs/ that would be helpful.