# LLDB ignored breakpoints set

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi3, breakpoints, lldb

I am trying to set up the lldb debugger to work on a Raspberry Pi and I faced several issues here. The first issue was unable to run the debugger, as I was shown
`error: process launch failed: Lost debug server connection`, as shown here.

[image: debugging using lldb-8]

After following the comments on this thread: [LLDB: process launch failed: Lost debug server connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232160/lldb-process-launch-failed-lost-debug-server-connection), I managed to get it to run on lldb-6.0

However, after setting a breakpoint at the main function and running it using `run`, it bypassed the breakpoint set and ended the program, as shown in the figure below.

[image: debugging using lldb-6.0]

I did not have this problem running on my desktop, but I can't seem to solve the issue on my Raspberry Pi. I have tried this with other programs as well, and it did not seem to work. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: fwiw you can set the breakpoint with just `b main`.  Does the program actually load and run at offset, or is it maybe being slid and lldb didn't see the slide happening.  Maybe add a printf("%p\n", main); in your program and see what it prints.  You can also turn on dynamic loader logging in lldb (log enable lldb dyld) before running and see where lldb thinks binaries are being loaded at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried the b main method and its still the same output. I tried putting a printf in the statement and yes it works, so the program actually completed running.
This is the output i got from `log enable lldb dyld`:

`lldb-6.0         DynamicLoaderDarwin::UseDYLDSPI: Use old DynamicLoader plugin
lldb-6.0         DynamicLoaderDarwin::UseDYLDSPI: Use old DynamicLoader plugin`

I managed to find a workaround from this issue but it is just a temporary solution. I had to make a while(1) loop and `Ctrl+C` to force a SIGSTOP to continue debugging

Comment: right, so my point was -- does the address breakpoint set is printing match the address (roughly) that printf() printed.  When you control-c, does lldb knows you're in main in your binary.  Does lldb know where this binary actually got landed in memory.  Once you press control-c to interrupt, if you do `breakpoint list`, does lldb show a reasonable address for main when the program is running (it should be updated to the actual main load address).